# HTML form submit issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, submit

Brand new to HTML, I have experience programming in other languages, just having an issue with html.
I've looked around to try to find a way to have a "double post" in html that posts all of instances needed.

The reason why i need the multiple forms as of now, is because the outer code takes in sales information, and the moves through an authorize page, but i can only get one or the other to trigger.

```
    <form method="post" action="sales_info_driver_page.cgi">

    Outer code here
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/su.php"><p>
    <input type="text"  name="Email" size="20"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Action" value="join-list" checked>Subscribe </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="ThanksURL" value="2222">
    </form>

    Outer code here

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="   Submit   " >
```

Is it even possible for the inner form to be submitted via either a javascript function or some other means? i read that it is not very plausable to have nested forms, so is there another way to have this section submit properly?

Need by 12-5-12 if at all possible! Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Why must you have separate forms?

Comment: You can submit part of your form using AJAX, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670180/howto-submit-a-part-of-a-form-using-jquery

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you say "Inner form" do you literally mean the forms are nested? If so, you probably don't want to go that route. Nested forms are invalid in HTML and will cause problems.

Comment: It's not that I have to have them nested, but i am not the original dev, and am jumping into this problem, just trying to fix up their bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to have multiple forms nested inside other forms, as it is invalid HTML...

If you want to submit a form from a link outside the form, just give the form an ID such as:
`<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/su.php" id="form1">`
and add the submit button back into the parameters of the `<form>`.

Then, wherever you want to submit the form, you can use a javascript handler:

eg:
`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">Submit Form1</a>`

Of course, it's better practice to use functions and not bind inline event handlers, but this is just an example and to demonstrate the use of `onclick` and form submission.

If you're using jQuery, you can just do: `onclick="$('#form1').submit();"`, which is much simpler.

I suppose it's possible to adapt the above method to submit all of the forms; and you can use jQuery/Javascript to find and collect all the values that you want to submit when the button is clicked, then use an Ajax call to send all the values to one destination.

Comment: how would one go about doing something like this? I'm pretty well experienced with c++ and get the function idea, just can't get the syntax for what i'm trying to do down.

Answer (score 0):

instead using form, you may used div for divisions of it

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/su.php">
<div>

Outer code here
</div>
<div><p>
<input type="text"  name="Email" size="20"><br>
<input type="radio" name="Action" value="join-list" checked>Subscribe </p>
<input type="hidden" name="ThanksURL" value="2222">
</div>

Outer code here

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="   Submit   " >
```